# android google maps not loading the map

Tags: android, google-maps

I searched through google about this bug and there was a fair amount of people 
with same problem, but all of their solutions didn't work for me.I would love for you to know that I am not experienced in asking question on this site so if you have any type of feedback on how to improve my question it will be more than welcome.Thanks.

the bug is that google map doesn't load the map and you'r left with a grey screen and the google logo on the bottom left corner.

this is my java file with the map:

```
package location.hive;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final int DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_with_map);

        String city = getIntent().getStringExtra("city");

        setTitle(getString(R.string.landon_hotel) + ", " + city);

        Hotel hotel = DataProvider.hotelMap.get(city);
        if (hotel == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_find_hotel) + ": "
                    + city, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        TextView cityText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityText);
        cityText.setText(hotel.getCity());

        TextView neighborhoodText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.neighborhoodText);
        neighborhoodText.setText(hotel.getNeighborhood());

        TextView descText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
        descText.setText(hotel.getDescription() + "\n");

        if (servicesOK() && initMap()) {

            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
            List<Address> list;
            try {
                list = gc.getFromLocationName(hotel.getAddress(), 1);
                Address address = list.get(0);
                double lat = address.getLatitude();
                double lng = address.getLongitude();
                LatLng latLong = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLong, 5);
                mMap.moveCamera(update);

                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(getString(R.string.landon_hotel) + ", " + city)
                        .position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                mMap.addMarker(options);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_finding_hotel), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(this.getLocalClassName(), e.getMessage());
            }

        }

    }

    public boolean servicesOK() {
        int result = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (result == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(result)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result, this, DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_connect_to_services), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean initMap() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMap = mapFrag.getMap();
        }
        return (mMap != null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    }

}
```

and this is my app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "location.hive"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

above is my gradle file  and
 here is  my Logcat error data:

```
combinedSignalIconId=0x7f020649/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mobileLabel=mobily wifiLabel="HUAWEI-B315-BF2B" emergencyOnly=false combinedLabel="HUAWEI-B315-BF2B" mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=3 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020575/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_2_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f02015b/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_2 mDataDirectionIconId=0x0/(null) mDataSignalIconId=0x7f020575/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_2_auto_rotate mDataTypeIconId=0x7f0203ef/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_data_connected_3g mQSDataTypeIconId=0x7f02015d/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3g mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f020649/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mQSWifiIconId=0x7f02032b/com.android.systemui:drawable/qs_tile_wifi_signal_4 mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f0205fc/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_inout mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f020625/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth
    02-27 16:29:29.695 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
    02-27 16:29:29.705 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
    02-27 16:29:29.705 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
    02-27 16:29:29.715 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
    02-27 16:29:30.575 3059-3164/? D/com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger: Got unexpected exception: java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject
    02-27 16:29:30.715 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=2 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f020649/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mobileLabel=mobily wifiLabel="HUAWEI-B315-BF2B" emergencyOnly=false combinedLabel="HUAWEI-B315-BF2B" mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=3 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020575/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_2_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f02015b/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_2 mDataDirectionIconId=0x0/(null) mDataSignalIconId=0x7f020575/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_2_auto_rotate mDataTypeIconId=0x7f0203ef/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_data_connected_3g mQSDataTypeIconId=0x7f02015d/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3g mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f020649/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mQSWifiIconId=0x7f02032b/com.android.systemui:drawable/qs_tile_wifi_signal_4 mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f02060a/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_out mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f020625/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth
    02-27 16:29:30.715 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
    02-27 16:29:30.715 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
    02-27 16:29:30.725 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
    02-27 16:29:30.725 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
    02-27 16:29:31.625 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 6 99 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 0x2 gsm|lte level=2
    02-27 16:29:31.625 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: updateTelephonySignalStrength: hasService=true ss=SignalStrength: 6 99 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 0x2 gsm|lte
    02-27 16:29:31.625 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: updateTelephonySignalStrength: iconLevel=2
    02-27 16:29:31.625 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: updateTelephonySignalStrength, No signal level. mPhoneSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_2_auto_rotate mDataSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_2_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_2 mContentDescriptionPhoneSignal = Phone two bars.
    02-27 16:29:31.735 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=2 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f020649/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mobileLabel=mobily wifiLabel="HUAWEI-B315-BF2B" emergencyOnly=false combinedLabel="HUAWEI-B315-BF2B" mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=3 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020575/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_2_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f02015b/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_2 mDataDirectionIconId=0x0/(null) mDataSignalIconId=0x7f020575/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_2_auto_rotate mDataTypeIconId=0x7f0203ef/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_data_connected_3g mQSDataTypeIconId=0x7f02015d/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3g mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f020649/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mQSWifiIconId=0x7f02032b/com.android.systemui:drawable/qs_tile_wifi_signal_4 mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f0205ff/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_no_inout mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f020625/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth
    02-27 16:29:31.735 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
    02-27 16:29:31.745 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
    02-27 16:29:31.745 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
    02-27 16:29:31.755 1387-1387/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
    02-27 16:29:32.165 904-1727/? D/BatteryService: !@BatteryListener : batteryPropertiesChanged!
    02-27 16:29:32.175 904-1727/? D/BatteryService: level:100, scale:100, status:2, health:2, present:true, voltage: 4387, temperature: 321, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, POGO powered:false, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303564, invalid charger:0, maxChargingCurrent:0
    02-27 16:29:32.175 904-1727/? D/BatteryService: online:4, current avg:450, charge type:1, power sharing:false, high voltage charger:false, capacity:280000, batterySWSelfDischarging:false, current_now:450
    02-27 16:29:32.175 904-904/? D/BatteryService: Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
    02-27 16:29:32.185 904-904/? I/MotionRecognitionService: Plugged
    02-27 16:29:32.185 904-904/? D/MotionRecognitionService:   cableConnection= 1
    02-27 16:29:32.185 904-904/? D/MotionRecognitionService: setPowerConnected | current backoffstate  = 1024 , state =1024
    02-27 16:29:32.185 904-904/? D/MotionRecognitionService: skip setTransmitPower. 
    02-27 16:29:32.195 1387-1387/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
    02-27 16:29:32.195 1387-1387/? I/PERF: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
    02-27 16:29:32.195 1387-1387/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
    02-27 16:29:32.205 1800-1800/? D/CommonServiceConfiguration: getStringValueSetting
    02-27 16:29:32.215 1387-1387/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:100 status:2 health:2
    02-27 16:29:32.215 1387-1387/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:100 status:2 health:2
    02-27 16:29:32.215 1387-1387/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:100 status:2 health:2
    02-27 16:29:32.235 1800-1800/? D/BatteryMonitor: new battery level: 100
```

Comment: could be an issue with your api key.

Comment: no it is not my api key used it in another app and still worked

Comment: The logcat is providing logs from the device or emulator and not this particular class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do 2 things

1. **ENABLE**  `Google Android Maps API`
2. Add code to `onMapReady` and call the callback in `onCreate`

*How to Enable Google Android Maps API*

- Login to your app in `https://console.developers.google.com/`
- Click `Enable APIs and Services`
- Click `Google Maps Android API`
- Click `ENABLE`

And secondly add the following code to your `DetailActivity.java`,

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final int DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;

    public GoogleMap mMap;

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        mMap = map;

        if (servicesOK() /*&& initMap()*/) {

            //Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
            //List<Address> list;
            try {
                //list = gc.getFromLocationName(hotel.getAddress(), 1);
                //Address address = list.get(0);

                double lat = 0.6856979;
                double lng = 16.8795434;
                LatLng latLong = new LatLng(lat, lng);
//                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLong, 5);
                Log.i("BEGINNING","Check this");
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLong));
                Log.i("Finishing","Check this");

                /*MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(getString(R.string.landon_hotel) + ", " + city)
                        .position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                mMap.addMarker(options);*/
                //onMapReady(mMap);

            } /*catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_finding_hotel), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/ catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Check this->", e.getMessage());
            }



        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_with_map);
        /*
        String city = getIntent().getStringExtra("city");
        setTitle(getString(R.string.landon_hotel) + ", " + city);
        Hotel hotel = DataProvider.hotelMap.get(city);
        if (hotel == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_find_hotel) + ": "
                    + city, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        TextView cityText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityText);
        cityText.setText(hotel.getCity());
        TextView neighborhoodText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.neighborhoodText);
        neighborhoodText.setText(hotel.getNeighborhood());
        TextView descText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
        descText.setText(hotel.getDescription() + "\n");
        */


        SupportMapFragment mapFrag =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
//            mMap = mapFrag.getMap();
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    public boolean servicesOK() {
        int result = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (result == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(result)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result, this, DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_connect_to_services), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

//    private boolean initMap() {
//        if (mMap == null) {
//
//        }
//        return (mMap != null);
//    }
}
```

Comment: Try to zoom in and zoom out on grey screen, is the map loading?

Comment: put it on github and give me the link, I will check it.

Comment: that is the url to my github project. the map is on DetailActivity.java, I commented most of the code but feel free to copy the code from the original post and trying again.one last thing the api key i removed it so you have to add one yourself

Comment: @RakanHabab, check my update and let me know if you are able to solve it as well.

Comment: yes please do, it's working for me. update the question with new logcat.

Answer (score 3):

In my case problem laid in hostname verification. If you have custom, global hostname verifier ensure that verification does not discard Google hostnames.

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier(){

    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session){

        //accept google hostnames or redesign your security policy
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it can be an easy problem. You need to check your Manifest file. It should have this:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_map_key" />
```